# Convert videos to iPod Touch-friendly formats

Tags: iphone, video-conversion, ipod, file-format

I have a bunch of Xvid videos lying around, and I would love to convert them to a format that will play on my iPod touch efficiently and quickly.

What free programs can do this? Although I am after something to run on Leopard, Windows programs wouldn't be bad either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a great crossplatform program for converting all kinds of stuff, especially to iPod formats

Answer (score 4):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/?article=details) will do this. MP4 is probably your best bet for a mix of efficiency and speed.

Comment: +1 for format recommendation as well. I use this on Linux works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

How about [Evom](http://thelittleappfactory.com/evom/)? I've only used it for small-ish videos, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nVidia CUDA GPU, you could use [Badaboom](http://www.badaboomit.com/). It takes 3-4 mins to convert a 700 MB movie with it.